# Merwry Ceiling Fan - Remote can't change speed

Tags: ceiling-fan

I just moved into a new house and they installed several Merwry ceiling fans by Home Decoration Collection.  However, they didn't install the receivers and remotes with the ceiling fans.  One fan is stuck on LOW and I've wanted to increase the speed.  Each fan has two wall switches for Light and Fan.  I purchased a universal receiver and remote from Amazon and installed it last night.  I was able to wire the fan to the receiver and the light directly to the fan.  I am able to use the On/Off function of the remote to control the fan, however I am unable to get the speed to increase.  It mentioned that you need to set the fan to 'HIGH' before installing the receiver, but this is a fan with no chains, and all speed changes have to be done using a remote.  Can you give me any advice here on why the remote is working with the receiver, but I'm unable to turn the speed up?  I can hear the click and everything is working with the wall switches.

Comment: can we have a picture please? How many wires does the fan has ?

Comment: The fan has 4 wires, and there are 4 wires coming out of the ceiling.  I wired the Black (Hot) to the Receiver to control the Fan with the remote, and I wired the Red (Hot) directly to the blue wire on the fan to control the light with the wall switch.  It's functioning as intended, just not allowing me to change speeds.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08NZCR65X/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza
That is the receiver I purchased.

Comment: If the fan itself doesn't have a pull chain to change speed (not even a short chain hanging from the fan motor?), then maybe it is unable to run at multiple speeds...

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I have 6 fans in the house, and 4 of them run at HIGH and 2 are running at LOW.  The builder didn't install the remotes that come with the fans when they renovated the house.  Someone else suggested perhaps it's a problem with the motor control circuit.